# javascript array traffic light

Tags: javascript, arrays

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<img id="H:\IT\traffic-light-red.jpg" src="H:\IT\traffic-light-red.jpg">

<button type="button" onclick="changeLights()">Change Lights</button>

<script>
var list = [
    "H:\IT\traffic-light-red.jpg",
    "H:\IT\traffic-light-red-amber.jpg",
    "H:\IT\traffic-light-green.jpg",
    "H:\IT\traffic-light-red.jpg"
];

var index = 0;

function changeLights() {
    index = index + 1;

    if (index == list.length) index = 0;

    var image = document.getElementById('light');
    image.src=list[index];
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I do not understand why the code isn't working. every time I try open it in a browser it doesn't show me the image. this is something I'm struggling to do in school and would appreciate of someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: Your images are on the filesystem? Browser cannot access your filesystem list that. Put them on http server first.. Secondly your image IDs and getElementById do not match... good luck!

Comment: You don't have element with an `id` of `'light'`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't choose correctly your image.

All you need is changing id of your img element;

```js
var list = [
  "https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/customicondesign-office6-shadow/256/trafficlight-red.png",
  "https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2012/05/07/04/43/button-47963_640.png",
  "https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/customicondesign-office6-shadow/128/trafficlight-green.png"
];

var index = 0;

function changeLights() {
    index = index + 1;

    if (index == list.length) index = 0;

    var image = document.getElementById('light');
    image.src=list[index];
}
```

```html
<img id="light" src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/customicondesign-office6-shadow/256/trafficlight-red.png" width="100" height="100">
<button type="button" onclick="changeLights()">Change Lights</button>
```

In this snippet images hosted from another websites or CDNs. Also, your image paths are look like wrong. Please check your image paths.

Answer (score 0):

If you put "H:\IT\traffic-light-red.jpg" in your browser's address bar will it work? Nope! cause it's trying to access an image on the file system. You need to use the [file protocol](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767731(v=vs.85).aspx). So it would be something like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<img id="H:\IT\traffic-light-red.jpg" src="H:\IT\traffic-light-red.jpg">

<button type="button" onclick="changeLights()">Change Lights</button>

<script>
var list = [
    "file:///H:/IT/traffic-light-red.jpg.html"
    "file:///H:/IT/traffic-light-red-amber.jpg",
    "file:///H:/IT/traffic-light-green.jpg",
    "file:///H:/IT/traffic-light-red.jpg"
];

var index = 0;

function changeLights() {
    index = index + 1;

    if (index == list.length) index = 0;

    var image = document.getElementById('light');
    image.src=list[index];
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

If the files were hosted somewhere on the web like dropbox you could also grab those links and it would work.

Answer (score 0):

your source of images are incorrect place your images near to your html file in root of your project directory and then use something like this for your sources: `<img src="image_url" />`

your id of your img elements does not match with getElementById method

Answer (score 0):

This is what I used, hope it helps!

```html
<html>
<head>
<b> <u> <i>Traffic Light System</i> </u> </b>
</head>
<body>

<p>Click the button to change to the next light.</p>

<img id="starting_light" src="http://mars.wiwi.hu-berlin.de/mediawiki/sk/images/thumb/1/1f/Red_Light_Icon.svg/232px-Red_Light_Icon.svg.png">

<button type="button" onclick="nextLightClick()">Next Light</button>

<script>

var lights = new Array("http://mars.wiwi.hu-berlin.de/mediawiki/sk/images/thumb/1/1f/Red_Light_Icon.svg/232px-Red_Light_Icon.svg.png","https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/45/Yellow_Light_Icon.svg/232px-Yellow_Light_Icon.svg.png","https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4b/Green_Light_Icon.svg");



var index = 0;
var lightsLen = lights.length;

function nextLightClick() {
    index++;

    if (index == lightsLen) 
        index = 0;

    var image = document.getElementById('starting_light');
    image.src = lights[index];
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```